# JS static files not working for Django Project

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

I am following this online countdown-tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZpujnQqcvAA to implement into my website. I feel I am missing something simple.

base.html

```
{% load static %}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- favicon -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="{% static 'favicon.ico' %}"/>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- jquery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>

    <!-- custom js-->
    {% block scripts %}
    {% endblock scripts %}

    <title>countdown to events</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container mt-3">
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock content %}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

main.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

    {% for obj in object_list %}
            <div>
                <a href={{obj.get_absolute_url}}>{{obj.name}}</a>
            </div>
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

countdown.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load static %}

{% block scripts %}
    <script scr={% static 'main.js' %} defer></script>
    
{% endblock scripts %}

{% block content %}
    <div class ="row">
        <div class = "col-5">
            <div>{{object.names}} will take place:</div>
        </div>
        <div class = "col-7">
            <div id="event-box">{{object.when|date:"M d, Y H:m:s"}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>Time left:</div>
    <div id ="count-down-box" class="text-center mt-3 h1">
        <div class ="spinner-border" role = "status"></div>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

main.js

```
console.log('hello world')

const eventBox = document.getElementById('event-box')
const countdownBox = document.getElementById('count-down-box')

console.log(eventBox.textContent)
const eventDate = Date.parse(eventBox.textContent)
console.log(eventDate)

setInterval(()=>{

    const now = new Date().getTime()
    //console.log(now)

    const diff = eventDate - now
    //console.log(diff)

    const d = Math.floor(eventDate / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) - (now / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)))
    const h = Math.floor((eventDate / (1000 * 60 * 60) - (now / (1000 * 60 * 60))) % 24)
    const m = Math.floor((eventDate / (1000 * 60) - (now / (1000 * 60))) % 60)
    const s = Math.floor((eventDate / (1000) - (now / (1000))) % 60)
    console.log(s)
    if (diff> 0){
        countdownBox.innerHTML = d + " days, " + h + " hours, " + m + " minutes, " + s + " seconds"
    }
    else{
        countdownBox.innerHTML = "countdown complete!"
    }



}, 1000)
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [ BASE_DIR / 'static']
```

http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/main.js

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('thesite.urls')),
    path('members/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('members/', include('members.urls')),

]+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

directory:

```
    site
    asite
    --urls.py
    members
    the site
    --models.py
    --templates
         --base.html
         --home.html
         --countdown.html
    static 
    --main.js
```

I have tried looking at other questions, clearing cache, and changing the static paths/directories and it will not load. All the other answers to this question suggest changing the static directors or adding a STATIC_ROOT, it still does not load on my end.

Comment: In which folder is the JS file located and do you have "django.contrib.staticfiles" in your settings for `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: And did you change the `urlpatterns`? See: [Serving static files during development](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development)

Comment: @Matthias in my static folder, urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('events.urls', namespace ='events'))
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root = settings.STATIC_ROOT)
I edited my urlpatterns aswell,

Comment: @aloeverragel if your static folder inside an app then it doesn't work

Comment: STATIC_ROOT is required. `script` tag needs quotations around `src` value. Please show your folder structure and add urls.py contents to the question.

Comment: @IvanStarostin he added main urls just see one comment before

Comment: @IvanStarostin STATIC_URL = '/static/'
#STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR , 'static']
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'), when I add static_root instead it gives me error of The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting.

Comment: Please update your question instead of posting to comments.

Comment: `STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT` this is correct. Set STATIC_ROOT as said. And show how you init BASE_DIR.